# php include path with variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, include

Is this:

```
include('summary_table.php?pid='.$profile_id);
```

invalid script?

If not, why won't it work?

Path is correct and `var_dump($profile_id);` returns the correct result.

**EDIT:** The reason for this method being required is, I am using JQuery in the page to refresh a div with `summary_table.php?pid='.$profile_id` every few mins so I have `$pid = $_GET['pid'];` in my summary_table.php.

The problem is the div will not fill with summary_table.php on load, it waits the few minutes for JQuery to fill it.

Comment: Yes, it is invalid syntax. Luckily, it's not needed, as the variable will be available inside the included script. So you can simply do `var_dump($profile_id)` inside of `summary_table.php`, and it'll work just fine.

Comment: It isn't HTTP unless it starts with `http://` or `https://`. File system does not have neither GET nor POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way will never work! Use this instead:

Index.php (or any other name):

```
<?php
include'summary_table.php';
echo $profile_id;
?>
```

Summary_table.php:

```
<?php
$profile_id = whatever you want here;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling URL in include, which is invalid.

Why dont you use $_GET['pid'] or $profile_id in summary_table.php.

It will always bring the data of desired pid.

Answer (score 0):

include is working just like you would have the content of it pasted instead of calling it.

```
include('summary_table.php');
```

and then inside summary_table.php:

```
$pid=$profile_id;
```